# How to omit an union type depending on field value

Tags: typescript, types

I have this type (come from third party library):

```
type StackActionType = {
    type: 'REPLACE';
    payload: {
        name: string;
        key?: string | undefined;
        params?: object;
    };
    source?: string;
    target?: string;
} | {
    type: 'PUSH';
    payload: {
        name: string;
        params?: object;
    };
    source?: string;
    target?: string;
} | {
    type: 'POP';
    payload: {
        count: number;
    };
    source?: string;
    target?: string;
} | {
    type: 'POP_TO_TOP';
    source?: string;
    target?: string;
};
```

I would like to infer remaining union types.
I can achieve that with field key/name. ex:

```
const action: StackActionType = ...;
if("payload" in action) {
  // action is infered with union types of: 'REPLACE', 'PUSH', 'POP' (contains "payload" field) and 'POP_TO_TOP' is omited 
}
```

But there is a way to achieve that using field value instead of field name, ex:

```
if(["PUSH", "REPLACE"].includes(action.type)) {
 // action should only infer union of 'REPLACE' & 'PUSH'. But this is not working...
}
```

Any idea (without copying/alter original type) ?

EDIT:

Here is a try with type guard & if:
[Typscript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgQQMbAJaoCrjQC8UA3gFBRVSiQBcUA5AOIDyA%20gEJowDSjAbkrUAznACuAJwwQA-AxHBJ2FAHMh1GgENJqiMHlRFytUIC%20UAD5lhVWhAaMAcmgBqASWZo8AUUG2oMC0QABs4LQATBgpNTRQtBAcjJRV1AM0gyQSRQzgAIwArCCwNajNSqjEpGUNjVIrtXX1alNNycvJyeygAZWAtDABrTBx8QigSGOp7RwAlHwAFABkePwag0PCom1jqeMSFVrTdqkGIEBaTVSsocRQIiAAzFQgIhoydbNzC4uAGjs0VWkckOVwa-SaBlB9XaNymdkIjgWAFUegAJfwfTaRaLpPYJJJ1NonQKfBA5Bj5IolAIA0QSYGXGGaCF6KHJMGw6zwmiIpgLVgLTHUDZhHE7E4YCQoYAMFDiBB5CCSf4NIE1aHE6Y6NlMtoWbkBGb8wXsPAcc1CtUMjUc5nayF6tIdLrjJxaABu2FUWlG6CwuBQEwlCPodq1VFFW2%201L%20AXVIPDxwdus1zqE5ClKEUUGwIndXp9fpGgeDAAoBn6GGWC97fYGS6gbmWywBKCYAPigtaLDYDqFbg4YldLedgiGQ-r9BEgNz6A2G-ZQM%20IXfscEeUBHTaIu6gACIqb99xnHncl1AIAAPBJgEIQCtL6s9%20uoRtB6wt9tELsv4tLwd2x5bBNzLPM-z7P1Hz9dsADJYLxKhoMDAA6bo90YFF0UYKxrG3FA0PGDD5mWVZGEHENYizMR7xQsJVGQ1AUKjSJW3%20dogA)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your solution will work if you instead use:

```
if (action.type == 'PUSH' || action.type == 'REPLACE') {}
```

Typescript cannot statically analyze the type possibilities when you use `[].includes` since an array can technically contain dynamic (runtime) values.

Comment: Not working for me:
`if (action.type === "PUSH" || action.type === "REPLACE") {
  console.log(action.payload); // Property 'payload' does not exist on type '{ type: "POP_TO_TOP"; source?: string | undefined; target?: string | undefined; }'
}`

Comment: What ts version are you on?  Here is a working example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGBjA1gQUcAlgewHYBVxoBeKAbwCgpqpRIAuKAcgCUBRABQBlUBhNpgG4qNMPBAAbbPAAmjSjUVRc8ALYRGAZ2AAnTLgDmwpTWQQQAfi279BqAB8oAV1wyIAM30QZxk1DE6appWUNgARgBWEBi+1AC+sVCa2E46iBAh2nqGiQg6BhDAmTY5FHEO5CLUdBrMHACqMAASQlX+4lKy8m2KKurW2UY9ovCBqsGM4VExbQltyanpxYO5owVFA7bC5Y4KNDWMTBwA8hytimKS0nKVflCIKbjAjLhOqmEQOolzigtpGZtSoo8utllsyhU9tUiIcThwAPr4Y6I07nGh-JaAobAtaFMGlOYUdwuDA4XBQCAADzUYAkEAAFEgsHhGHAkGhSXhCJAAJS3GiYdxQRmc3AAOhqUGIpCOjRaDkcTLJEqIUpl7G4fAEfKhSgeuGSdLFUgMIuZ4sunRkPO+ZSAA

Comment: You right, I simplified too much my example. Here is my try with type guard (see my post edit)